# Does a using namespace directive make names usable in inlined functions?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, using, compiler-bug

Consider declaring an unconstrained `ns::operator*`. After `using namespace ns` in block scope and calling a function `foo<T>`, clang uses `ns::operator*` when reading the iterators of a range-based loop inside `foo`. There are no other types from `ns` involved, so ADL should result in no candidates.

In the following example, `static_assert` fails with the message:

> error: static assertion failed due to requirement 'std::is_same_v<const int &, const custom_type &>'

The assembly code shows that `ns::operator*` is used by clang. The assertion passes for gcc and msvc!

```cpp
namespace ns {

template <typename T>
constexpr auto operator*(T&& /*value*/) {
    struct custom_type {};
    return custom_type{};
};

}  // namespace ns

template <typename T>
constexpr void foo() {
    std::vector<T> vec{};
    for (const auto& curr : vec) {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<const T&, decltype(curr)>);
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace ns;
    foo<int>();
}
```

Here's a godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/z5vf48Mda.

I'm not able to reproduce the problem by invoking `operator*` inside `foo` manually. Additionally, the assertion passes for clang when `foo` is not templated *or* not `constexpr`. It's as if clang inlines `foo<T>` and therefore treats `ns::operator*` as a valid candidate. I'm almost sure that clang is broken, because the problem only occures when using range-based loops.

Is either clang or gcc/msvc correct, or are we dealing with unspecified/undefined behaviour?

Comment: Moving the `using namespace ns;` in `foo` make only gcc to fail [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/evMfPbdfE)

Comment: And moving it globally, only msvc succeed [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c1Mzhza1h).

Comment: Clang issue reported: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/76366

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in Clang. The `using namespace ns` in `main` shouldn't have any effect on the lookup in `foo` and it should be impossible to find `ns::operator*` in `foo` by any form of lookup.

Your observations suggest to me that there is a bug in how lookup is handled in range-for loops (which have some special lookup rules).

Inlining functions is a compiler optimization under the as-if rule. It never has impact on the behavior or well-formedness of a program. It shouldn't affect lookup in any way.

Comment: I think that `operator*` is a viable candidate if it's imported into the global namespace with `using namespace` and if it accepts all types. I would have expected the `operator*` of the vector's iterator to be a better match, since it should be more specialized. That's not actually gauranteed by the standard though and you could implement all standard library iterators using a single `operator++` with SFINAE or a big `if constexpr` dispatcher. So this behavior by clang might even be compliant.

Comment: Interestingly, clang's assertion fails for both `-stdlib=libc++` and `-stdlib=libstdc++`, so this is likely a bug in overload resolution, not a standard library design issue.

Comment: @JanSchultke But the `using namespace ns;` directive is only active in the block scope of `main`, not in the global scope. It can't affect lookup in `foo`.